# ELPA archives directory contents: the data structure used?

Tags: package-repositories, data-structures

I just stumbled across the archives directory of my .emacs.d/archives/ . Here's the beginning of `.../archives/gnu/archive-contents`

```
(1
 (ace-window .
         [(0 9 0)
          ((avy
        (0 2 0)))
          "Quickly switch windows." single
          ((:url . "https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window")
           (:keywords "window" "location"))])
 (ack .
      [(1 5)
       nil "interface to ack-like tools" tar
       ((:keywords "tools" "processes" "convenience")
    (:url . "https://github.com/leoliu/ack-el"))]) ...
```

Can someone "deep in the lore" enlighten me to what this is about, specifically, how this s-expression AST(?) is built, on what criteria. What is the data schema used here, et cetera....

Comment: This question is really too broad ("What is this about?"), and you pose several questions in it. And then you pose more questions in comments to @wasamasa's answer. And then you add another, separate question that is nearly identical, and nearly as broad. Q&A for this site should be specific, typically how-to, questions. Asking what considerations were involved in designing a particular package repository (or even a particular library) is too broad to be useful here, IMHO. You might want to try a site such as Reddit, which is more geared toward discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a list of packages available in the specific ELPA repository.
It's created by the admin of that repository and downloaded by Emacs
to know what's installable.

Here's a pseudo-grammar:

```
PACKAGE-ARCHIVES: (PACKAGE-ARCHIVE-VERSION PACKAGE ...)
PACKAGE-ARCHIVE-VERSION: <integer>
PACKAGE: (PACKAGE-NAME . PACKAGE-DESCRIPTOR)
PACKAGE-NAME: <symbol>
PACKAGE-DESCRIPTOR: [VERSION DEPENDENCIES DESCRIPTION TYPE METADATA]
VERSION: (<integer> ...)
DEPENDENCIES: ((PACKAGE-NAME VERSION) ...)
DESCRIPTION: <string>
TYPE: single | tar
METADATA: (METADATUM ...)
METADATUM: (<keyword> ARG ...)
```

Comment: Know where the code is that handles (creates, reads) these archive files?

Comment: It's in `package.el`, `package-x.el` contains a bit more for uploading and publishing packages.

Comment: Can anyone show me more of these sorts of "in the wild" uses of s-expressions for data management? I'm really needing to get my head around this -- beyond the baby examples in Lisp/Scheme textbooks. If not anyone reading this, then maybe suggest the proper forum(s)? Also, as a beginner, I'm not really grokking your "pseudo-grammar" wasamasa. Can you direct me to a tutorial of this pseudo-grammar?

Comment: Read actual lisp source code and you'll discover more of these.  There is no tutorial for this grammar because I made it up on the spot and consider it pretty easy to read:  "Package-archives are a list of a package-archive-version and one or more packages, packave-archive-version is an integer, package is a cons of a package-name and a package-descriptor, package-name is a symbol, etc.".