# Data structure for ELPA archive use of dotted pair

Tags: package-repositories, data-structures

As a belated follow-up to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/elpa-archives-directory-contents-the-data-structure-used), can someone enlighten me why the data structure used in the ELPA `archive-contents` files is a dotted pair of a name (symbol) and a vector that contains a great many things?

What is the advantage of doing it this way? It seems too intentional to just be a random stab. What precedent is this building on?

```
(1
 (ace-window .
         [(0 9 0)
          ((avy (0 2 0)))
          "Quickly switch windows." single
          ((:url . "https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window")
           (:keywords "window" "location"))])
```

Comment: This is nearly a dup of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/elpa-archives-directory-contents-the-data-structure-used, and like that question it is too broad or primarily opinion-based. To get the skinny about such a design decision my suggestion would be to ask its author. (And again, Reddit is maybe a good place to ask such a question.)

Comment: I can't comment on the vector structure, but I'll just add that a list of dotted pairs is an association list; so once that structure has been read, the vector for `ace-window` could be obtained with `(cdr (assq 'ace-window ALIST))`

Comment: That was my question -- where I did not ask this particular question. I now want to know why this particular strategy. It seems too unique to be just some shoot-from-the-hip thing. If anyone has seen it before, please enlighten me. Yes, phils, I'm beginning to guess that a `(cdr (assq 'ace-window THELIST)) would deliver the vector, but that's my question: what advantage is gained here by using a vector instead of just more nested lists? Other ELPA repos use the same strategy as well. Over in Clojure I've heard they encourage vectors and arrays. Is this faster, better?

Comment: Vectors (along with other array types) provide constant-time access to their elements (unlike lists, which have linear time access); so yes, there are benefits to using vectors when they are suitable.  Refer to `C-h i g (elisp)Sequences Arrays Vectors`